# Estimation of the conditional density functions

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Suppose we have a random vector $x=[x_1, x_2, ..., x_{10}]\in\mathbb{R}^{10}$. Obviously, $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_{10}$ are random variables theirselves. I have 500 observed samples of $x$ which I am going to use in order to estimate the following density functions (using parametric estimation or kernel density estimation):

$Pr(x_1)$

$Pr(x_2|x_1)$

$Pr(x_3|x_2, x_1)$

$Pr(x_4|x_3, x_2, x_1)$

$\vdots$

$Pr(x_{10}|x_1, x_2, ..., x_9)$

The first one (i.e., $Pr(x_1)$) is quite easy; all I need to do is to collect $x_1$ from all samples and run my estimation algorithm on. My question is: which pieces of the data should I use for the estimation of other ones (which are conditional)?

To make my question clear, take, for example, another random variable $y\in\mathbb{R}$, where I have 1000 samples of it, of which, 500 belong to class1 ($C_1$) and the other 500 belong to class2 ($C_2$). If I wanted to estimate $Pr(y|C_1)$ based on this data, I would have separated the 500 samples of class 1 and fed them to my density estimation algorithm. Similar to this example, which part of data should I separate to be able to estimate $Pr(x_2|x_1)$, $Pr(x_3|x_2, x_1)$, ..., $Pr(x_{10}|x_1, x_2, ..., x_9)$?

Comment: You might find it helpful to recognize *regression* in all of these expressions.  Thus, you posit a sequence of nine regression problems that you can solve separately.  *How* you do that depends on your probability model.  (With so little data, you will need one: a non-parametric solution is likely to be very uncertain.)

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. However, I didn't quite understand your proposed solution. So, you suggest that I should solve a regression problem for, say, $x_3$ based on $x_1$ and $x_2$ to find the relationship. What should I do after that to obtain (estimate) the probability densities?

Comment: You have to do a *full* regression.  That is, it doesn't suffice just to estimate the conditional expectation.  OLS is a "full" regression method when it assumes a conditional Normal response, for instance.  Its generalizations, such as Generalized Linear Models, also provide the conditional distributions.  Quantile regression can be used in a non-parametric way to estimate the conditional distributions.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I studied GLMs a little, and I understood your solution, which I think is a good one. I was wondering is there another way rather than using GLMs? For example, directly using kernel density estimation methods (e.g., Parzen windows) on data.

Comment: That's unlikely to work for such a small dataset.  For some intuition, note that each of the $x_i$ must vary -- that is, it must have at least two distinct values.  If they aren't completely dependent, we would therefore expect to estimate densities in the neighborhoods of approximately $2^{10}=1024$ points.  Since you have only $200$ observations, your estimates will be quite imprecise.  This is the *curse of dimensionality.*

Comment: @whuber $x$ is the signal of a specific EEG channel; so, I can downsample it. Assume that now $x$ is a 40-dimensional vector. However, I couldn't use GLMs att all! I tried to fit a GLM with 'normal' distribution for response variable, and the 'logit' link function, but Matlab gave me warnings and returned complex values for the coefficients!!